# C# Passing of value from MDI parent form to child

Tags: c#, forms, mdi

I need help on how to pass value from MDI parent form to child form. 
In my parent form I have two radio buttons, MALE and FEMALE, I will choose one of these and by clicking the button will send the assigned value to the child form.
Please see my code below:

Parent Form:

```
private void ButtonSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.rbMale.Checked)
            {
                string gender= "MALE";
                frmChild childform = new frmChild ();
                childform.GetGender = gender;

                frmChild  newMDIChild = new frmChild (); 
                newMDIChild.MdiParent = this; 
                newMDIChild.Show(); 

            }

            else if (this.rbFemale.Checked)
            {
                string gender= "FEMALE";
                frmChild childform = new frmChild ();
                childform.GetGender = gender;

                frmChild  newMDIChild = new frmChild (); 
                newMDIChild.MdiParent = this; 
                newMDIChild.Show(); 

            }
    }
```

Child Form:

```
public string GetGender { get; set; }

 private void frmChild_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GetGender  == Convert.ToString("MALE"))
            {
                 /*my code here*/
            }
            else if (GetGender  == Convert.ToString("FEMALE"))
            {
                /*my code here*/
            }
        MessageBox.Show(GetGender);
        }
```

I also temporarily put a MessageBox to let me know if it really fetch the value from the parent form, but it only returns empty.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645283/pass-value-to-child-window-form-parent-page)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210717/pass-value-from-parent-form-to-child-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating two instances of your childForm, one for assigning the gender and other for showing it. You only need one instance, change your if else statement

```
...
if (this.rbMale.Checked)
    {
       string gender= "MALE";    
       frmChild  newMDIChild = new frmChild (); 
       newMDIChild.GetGender = gender;
       newMDIChild.MdiParent = this; 
       newMDIChild.Show(); 
    }
...
```